# ?Como realizar una función almacenada de postgresql con salida de un json y varchar?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, funciones, plpgsql

Como realizar una función almacenada de postgresql con salida de un json y varchar. Se tiene en el ejemplo una consulta de barias tablas de donde obtengo el json, para el retorno de datos se desea retornar dos valores varchar y uno json. El script que a continuación muestro es un ejemplo de como lo plantee ... retorno error

Ejemplo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION consl_lista(in intid_persona integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (v_end_code VARCHAR, v_message VARCHAR,resultado JSON) AS $$

BEGIN        
v_end_code  := '99999';
    v_message   := 'Error';

select array_to_json(array_agg(c.*)) into resultado

from (

SELECT 
            pers.nombre, 
            pers.ap_paterno,
            pers.ap_materno,
            pers.ci,
            pers.exp_ci,
            pers.edad,
--          (pers.nombre||' ' ||pers.ap_paterno||' '||pers.ap_materno) as nombre_completo,
            pro.nomprofesion,
            para.detalle,
            para.descripcion,
            perf.nombre_perfil,
            perf.nivel_acceso,
            usr.nom_usuario,
            usr.estado_usr
        FROM usuario as usr
        left join persona as pers
        on pers.id_persona = usr.id_persona
        left join perfil as perf
        on perf.id_perfil =usr.id_perfil
        left join profesion as pro
        on pro.id_profesion = usr.id_profesion
        join parametrica as para
        on para.id_parametricas = pro.id_especialidad
        where usr.id_estado <>3 and pers.id_persona=intid_persona) as c;
    v_message = 'Accion realizada correctamente';
    v_end_code = '00000';
  RETURN;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Le hice pequeñas correcciones a tu función, así debeía funcionar.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION consl_lista(IN intid_persona INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE (v_end_code VARCHAR, v_message VARCHAR, resultado JSON) AS $$

BEGIN   

    RETURN QUERY SELECT '00000'::VARCHAR, 'Accion realizada correctamente'::VARCHAR, JSON_AGG(c.*)
        
            FROM (SELECT 
                    pers.nombre, 
                    pers.ap_paterno,
                    pers.ap_materno,
                    pers.ci,
                    pers.exp_ci,
                    pers.edad,
            --          (pers.nombre||' ' ||pers.ap_paterno||' '||pers.ap_materno) as nombre_completo,
                    pro.nomprofesion,
                    para.detalle,
                    para.descripcion,
                    perf.nombre_perfil,
                    perf.nivel_acceso,
                    usr.nom_usuario,
                    usr.estado_usr
                FROM usuario AS usr 
                LEFT JOIN persona AS pers ON pers.id_persona = usr.id_persona
                LEFT JOIN perfil AS perf ON perf.id_perfil =usr.id_perfil
                LEFT JOIN profesion AS pro ON pro.id_profesion = usr.id_profesion
                INNER JOIN parametrica AS para ON para.id_parametricas = pro.id_especialidad
                WHERE usr.id_estado <> 3 AND pers.id_persona = intid_persona) AS c;
        
END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Para usar la función tenés dos maneras (varian en como retornan la información):

```
SELECT * FROM consl_lista(1);

ó

SELECT consl_lista(1);
```